# Only search mongoose model for keys in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a search to filter results from a mongoose model. All the filter options except for two need to queried into Model1. The other two will query those results in Model2.

Before I added these last two options, I had the search working like so:

```
var filterOptions = req.body;
    for(var key in filterOptions) {
    if(filterOptions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        filterOptions[key] = new RegExp(filterOptions[key], "i");
    }
}

Model1.find(filterOptions, function(err, results) {
    //Use the results to search Model2.
})
```

I'm getting stuck how can I specify to only query Model1 with keys that are in that model. (Or, if there's a way to edit the filterOptions object to not include the last two options.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but with an utility framework like [lodash](http://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) this can be done in few lines of code:

```
// require lodash first
var _ = require('lodash');

(...)

// lodash way of doing the transformation into regexp objects
var filterOptions = _.transform(req.body, function(result, value, key) {
  result[key] = new RegExp(value, "i");
});

// Get all keys of Model1 from its schema
var model1keys = _.keys(Model1.schema.paths); 

// create copy of filterOptions with keys of model1    
var model1Filter = _.pick(filterOptions, model1keys);

// create copy of filterOptions without keys of model1
var model2Filter = _.omit(filterOptions, model1keys); 

Model1.find(model1Filter, function(err, results) {
    (....)
})
```